# How to redirect old url to new domain url in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have b een trying to redirect old urls to new domain url using htaccess file. with 301 redirect codes. but the old urls redirecting with same one with new domain urls.     I have tried with following code
**Htaccess file**

```
      ##
      # @package    Joomla
       # @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
       # @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

  ##
   # READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
    # 
    # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
   IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

   ## Mod_rewrite in use.

   RewriteEngine On



   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]



   #for http to https
  ##RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
   ##RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

   #for www 
   ##RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
##RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
     # If you experience problems on your site block out the 
 operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via 
  URL.
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
   # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root 
    homepage
   RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
   #
 ## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

   # RewriteBase /

  ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  #
   # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
   # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
  #
  ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

   Redirect 301 /x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/  
    https://www.example1.com/category/exurl
```

output
when i typing in address https://www.example.com/x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/  it is redirecting to https://www.example1.com/x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/

expected output
when i typing in address https://www.example.com/x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/ should redirect to
https://www.example1.com/category/exurl

Comment: It doesn’t appear to be doing anything. Where exactly are you putting this rule? Do you have existing directives?

Comment: redirect urls are redirecting to same urls not to the new one

Comment: What URL are you requesting? (I see you've just edited your question to change the domain in the "output" - does this imply you are requesting a different domain?)

Comment: yes from old domain old url  to new domain urls not redirecting it is redirect to same old one with new domain url

Comment: So, what is the actual URL you are requesting? And do you have existing directives in your  `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: actual url i am requesting is https://example1.com/newurl from olddomain url /iwantto/la
no i dont have any other htaccess. these are new directives in htaccess file

Comment: "actual url i am requesting is `https://example1.com/newurl`" - But that's the "newurl"?! What "old" URL are you requesting in order to test the redirect directives in your `.htaccess` file? (Also, test with 302 temporary redirects. 301s are cached persistently. Clear your browser cache.)

Comment: old url /i want to /  to https://example.com/banking

Comment: And how does that relate to the rule you posted in the question?!

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what "old" URLs you are requesting, what the expected response is and the actual directives you are using in your `.htaccess` file. You are using different URLs in comments to the example you posted in the question - this does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  RewriteEngine On
>
>
>
>  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
> RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
>
>    :
>    :
>    :
>
> Redirect 301 /x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/  
>  https://www.example1.com/category/exurl
> ```

Because the first rule redirects everything from `example.com` to **the same URL** at `example1.com`. Note that the first rule redirects to HTTP, not HTTPS.

Your `Redirect` directive isn't doing anything.

Regardless of the order of the directives in the file, the mod_rewrite directives (`RewriteRule` - first rule) are processed before mod_alias (`Redirect` - second rule). So simply changing the order of the directives does not help.

You need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (not mod_alias `Redirect`) and place the directive *before* the generic rule that redirects everything else.

The nature of these directives (and your file) would appear to suggest that both `example.com` and `example1.com` resolve here so you need to check the requested `Host` as part of the rule (something which is not possible with the `Redirect` directive).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "example.com/x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/" (trailing slash)
#  to "https://www.example1.com/category/exurl" (no trailing slash)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^x-ee-ee/sub-category/ererrre/$ https://www.example1.com/category/exurl [R=301,L]

# Redirect everything else to the same URL at "example1.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that the behaviour of the `RewriteRule` directive is not quite the same as the `Redirect` directive. The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix matching and copies everything after the match onto the end of the target URL - but I assume you are not expecting this as you had a mismatch of trailing slashes which would have resulted in a malformed redirect.

Note also that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does *not* start with a slash, unlike the `Redirect` directive.

If `example.com` and `example1.com` actually do point to different hosts then you can remove the preceding `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `HTTP_HOST`. But if that's the case then you could remove most of the other directives as well, since they wouldn't doing anything.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> how to rewrite this url RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=478&catid=16$ `https://www.example1.com/checking/debit-cards` [R=301,L]

I assume you mean "redirect". The `RewriteRule` *pattern* only matches against the URL-path. In order to match the query string part of the URL you need to use an additional *condition* and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =option=com_content&view=article&id=478&catid=16
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example1.com/checking/debit-cards [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* (ie. `=option=com_content&view....`) treats it as an exact match string comparison, not a regex.

**UPDATE#2:** The `QSD` flag is required to discard the original query string from the redirected response.

---

> **UPDATE#3:** Also i would like to redirect RewriteRule ^/images/docs/ATM-Dispute-Form.pdf$ `https://www.example1.com/tools/security-center` [R=301,L]

As noted above, "the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash", so this should be written:

```
RewriteRule ^images/docs/ATM-Dispute-Form\.pdf$ https://www.example1.com/tools/security-center [R=301,L]
```

Don't forget to backslash-escape literal dots in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*

> Also can i access backend of old domain url `www.example.com/administrator/index.php?SecureJscadmin=xxx` we need to keep alive this url alone in old domain

You can try adding an exception to the last rule that redircts everything else. For example:

```
# Redirect everything else to the same URL at "example1.com"
# EXCEPT "/administrator/index.php?SecureJscadmin=xxx"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^administrator/index\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^SecureJscadmin= 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the expression, so it is successful when it does not match.

Comment: how to rewrite this url RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=478&catid=16$ https://www.example1.com/checking/debit-cards [R=301,L]

Comment: @mike You need an additional _condition_. I've updated my answer.

Comment: it iredirecing to https://www.example1.com/checking/debit-cards?option=com_content&view=article&id=478&catid=16

Comment: @mike Ah, sorry, you need to add the `QSD` flag to discard the query string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also i would like to redirect RewriteRule ^/images/docs/ATM-Dispute-Form.pdf$ https://www.example1.com/tools/security-center [R=301,L] Also can i access backend of old domain url www.example.com/administrator/index.php?SecureJscadmin=xxx we need to keep alive this url alone in old domain

Comment: @mike I've updated my answer to address those two additional points.